# if request.user.is_anonymous: - Else: is not working well

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a row in DB which have 2 different conditions, when there is no user logged in, and when a user is logged in

I used

```
if request.user.is_anonymous:
 [....]
else:
 [....]
```

But it only saves to DB when the 1st line is true which is `if request.user.is_anonymous:` but it never saves to DB when a user is logged in .

```
def add_ad_mod(request):
    created_otp = uuid.uuid4().hex[:6].upper()
    current_user = request.user
    current_ip = get_client_ip(request)
    selected = Temp.objects.filter(created_by_ip=current_ip).order_by('-created_at')[0]
    selected_category = selected.cat
    classi = Category.objects.filter(category_name__icontains="Classifieds")[0]
    jobs = Category.objects.filter(category_name__icontains="Jobs")[0]
    if request.user.is_anonymous:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            add_ad_mod_form = AddAdModForm(request.POST, request.FILES, cat=selected_category)
            if add_ad_mod_form.is_valid():
                model_instance = add_ad_mod_form.save(commit=False)
                model_instance.category = selected_category
                model_instance.post_otp = created_otp
                model_instance.save()
                add_ad_mod_form.save_m2m()
                current_email = model_instance.email
                send_mail(
                    'Activate your Ad on Jehlum',
                    'Use the code ' + created_otp + '.',
                    'test@jehlem.org',
                    [model_instance.email],
                    fail_silently=False,
                )
                request.session['created_otp'] = created_otp  # set 'student_id' in the session
                request.session['current_email'] = current_email  # set 'student_id' in the session
            return redirect('post_confirm')
        else:
            add_ad_mod_form = AddAdModForm(cat=selected_category)
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            add_ad_mod_form = AddAdModForm(request.POST, request.FILES, cat=selected_category)
            if add_ad_mod_form.is_valid():
                model_instance = add_ad_mod_form.save(commit=False)
                model_instance.created_by = current_user.email
                model_instance.category = selected_category
                model_instance.email = current_user.email
                model_instance.post_otp = 0
                if request.user.is_superuser:
                    model_instance.is_active = True
                else:
                    model_instance.is_active = False
                model_instance.save()
                add_ad_mod_form.save_m2m()
            return redirect('post_success')
        else:
            add_ad_mod_form = AddAdModForm(cat=selected_category)

    add_ad_mod_form = AddAdModForm(cat=selected_category)

    context = {
        'add_ad_mod_form': add_ad_mod_form,
        'selected_category': selected_category,
        'classi': classi,
        'jobs': jobs,
    }
    return render(request, 'add_ad_mod.html', context)
```

Comment: did you check is `add_ad_mod_form.is_valid()` when user `not is_anonymous`?

Comment: @BearBrown yes i did , check the code after the `else:`

Comment: no your code after the `else` is not check for errors

Comment: @BearBrown I have `add_ad_mod_form.is_valid()` after `else` , if there is another line that am missing please point at it

Comment: `if add_ad_mod_form.is_valid()` ... and after `else` you should not reinitial form to see errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_anonymous` is a method and must therefore be called:

```
if request.user.is_anonymous():  # note parentheses
    # ...
```

You often see the version without parentheses in django **templates** where the render engine will implicitly call the function. In common Python code, however, `user.is_anonymous` references a function object which is always truthy, regardless of what a call to that function would return.

Comment: it returns `'bool' object is not callable`

Comment: go with `if not request.user.is_authenticated:` to see the change @AhmedWagdi

Comment: Do you have a custom user model? Since both `AbstractBaseUser` and `AnonymousUser` which are the usual types of `request.user` implement `is_ananymous` as a method, not a field or property.

Comment: @LemayzeurI did,, and it gives no errors but still not saving to DB when the user is authenticated

Comment: @schwobaseggl yes I have a custom user model

Comment: @schwobaseggl `is_anonymous` and `is_authenticated` both became properties  in django 2.0 (actually since 1.10 but with a compat hack allowing them to be used as both properties or methods in 1.10 and 1.11), cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_anonymous

Answer (score 1):

Since django 1.10 `is_anonymous` become a bool object, and no longer a method. In older versions, this was a method. Removed in Django 2.0.

As it clearly mentioned in the [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_anonymous)

**is_anonymous:** Read-only attribute which is always False. This is a way of differentiating User and AnonymousUser objects. Generally, you should prefer using `is_authenticated` to this attribute.

Instead of `is_anonymous`, go with `is_authenticated`

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    # authenticated user stuff
else:
    # Anonymous user
```